# WPF MVVM passing data between viewmodel but property not updating

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm making a Window to manage the users who using laptop. I have the window named "LaptopWindow" which contain a TextBox to display the user id of the one using it. I have made a button to open new UserControl named "FindEmployeeUC" to find the "EmpID" by select the row in DataGrid of UserControl and pass it back to the TextBox in "LaptopWindow".

I got the selected row of the DataGrid and use the property name "SelectedUA" to hold it inside the view model "UserAccountViewModel".

When OnPropertyChanged event fire I call the instance of "LaptopManagementViewModel" (this view model is bound with "LaptopWindow") and set the EmpID to the TextBox in "LaptopWindow" by the property named "ReceiverID"

The property "ReceiverID" got value but the UI of "LaptopWindow" didn't get update.

I tried to use Delegate, Singleton pattern, It had the same result.

Here is some code to explain more what I'm facing

- The "LaptopWindow" xaml:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource inputControl}">
      <TextBlock Text="Người nhận"/>
      <TextBox Name="txtReceiver" Text="{Binding ReceiverID,Source={StaticResource vmLaptopManagement}}" Margin="0,0,30,0"/>   
</StackPanel>

<!--Button open FindEmpUC -->
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Width="30" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,4,4,4" Command="{Binding CmdFindEmp}">
      <Image Source="/imgs/find-48.png" Stretch="Uniform"  />
</Button>
```

- The "LaptopManagementViewModel":

```
//the userAccountVM
      UserAccountViewModel userAccountVM;

//the constructor
  public LaptopManagementViewModel(UserAccountViewModel userAccountVM)
        {
            LstDVUS = LaptopManagementBLL.Instance.GetDVUsageStatuses();           
            LstLaptop = LaptopManagementBLL.Instance.GetLaptopsInfo();

            this.userAccountVM = userAccountVM;
            ReceiverID = this.userAccountVM.SelectedUA.EmpID;
        }
//the ReceiverID property
        string receiverID;

        public string ReceiverID
        {
            get { return receiverID; }
            set
            {
                receiverID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ReceiverID");
            }
        }
//function open FindEmployeeUC
 private void FindEmployee(object obj)
        {
            //show findEmployee UC
            Window wd = new Window()
            {
                Content = new FindEmployeeUC(),                
            };            
            wd.ShowDialog();

        }
```

- The "FindEmployeeUC" xaml:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding LstUA}" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUA,Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="EmpID" Binding="{Binding EmpID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="EmpName" Binding="{Binding EmpName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position" Binding="{Binding Position}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="LineGroup" Binding="{Binding LineGroup}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

- The "UserAccountViewModel":

```
//The property "SelectedUA"
        UserAccountModel selectedUA;

        public UserAccountModel SelectedUA
        {
            get { return selectedUA; }
            set
            {
                if(selectedUA!=value)
                {
                    selectedUA = value;
                    LaptopManagementViewModel laptopVM = new LaptopManagementViewModel(this);

                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUA");

                }

            }
        }
```

I expect to get the EmpID for the TextBox in "LaptopWindow". I attach a picture for more detail:
[image: The image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `OnPropertyChanged` event invocator you are always creating a new instance of `UserAccountViewModel`. This instance is never referenced in your XAML code, therefore your view can't see this new instances.
Since view model have a state you typically use a single instance for a binding target.

I removed the parameterized constructor to enable the instantiation in XAML (the instance is assigned to the `UserAccountVM` property from XAML) and also removed the reference to `LaptopManagementViewModel` from `UserAccountViewModel`. I created the view model instances and added them to the `ResourceDictionary` of App.xaml. 
I also added a `PropertyChanged` event handler to the `LaptopManagementViewModel` to listen for changes of `UserAccountViewModel.SelectedUA`.

It is also highly recommended to avoid string literals. Instead of calling `OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty")` you should use the free compiler support by applying [`nameof()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof): `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyClass.MyProperty))`. I replaced the corresponding code. You now get rid of typos and get full support of compiler checks and refactoring tools (e.g. renaming).

Also stay away from Singletons. They smell strong.

Last complaint: make fields always `private` (or `protected`), especially when they are property backing fields. If you don't use any access modifier then `internal` will apply implicitly. Which is equivalent to `public` inside a shared assembly and fields should never be exposed.

[Microsoft Docs recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) :

> Generally, you should use fields only for variables that have private or protected accessibility. Data that your class exposes to client code should be provided through methods, properties and indexers. By using these constructs for indirect access to internal fields, you can guard against invalid input values. A private field that stores the data exposed by a public property is called a backing store or backing field.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:class="App">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

      <UserAccountViewModel x:Key="UserAccountViewModel" />

      <LaptopManagementViewModel x:Key="LaptopManagementViewModel">
        <LaptopManagementViewModel.UserAccountVM>
          <StaticResource ResourceKey="UserAccountViewModel" />
        </LaptopManagementViewModel.UserAccountVM>
      </LaptopManagementViewModel>

  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**LaptopWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:class="LaptopWindow">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="LaptopManagementViewModel" />
  </Window.DataContext>

  ...
</Window>
```

**FindEmployeeUC.xaml**

```
<Window x:class="FindEmployeeUC">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="UserAccountViewModel" />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <DataGrid 
    ...
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

**LaptopManagementViewModel.cs**

```
public class LaptopManagementViewModel
{
  private UserAccountViewModel userAccountVM;
  public UserAccountViewModel UserAccountVM
  {
    get => userAccountVM; 
    set
    {
      userAccountVM = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UserAccountVM));

      if (userAccountVM != null)
      {
        // Always clean up event handlers to avoid memory leaks
        userAccountVM.PropertyChanged -= UpdateReceiverIdOnPropertyChanged;
      }

      userAccountVM.PropertyChanged += UpdateReceiverIdOnPropertyChanged;
    }
  }

  // The constructor is now parameterless for the use in XAML
  public LaptopManagementViewModel()
  {
    LstDVUS = LaptopManagementBLL.Instance.GetDVUsageStatuses();
    LstLaptop = LaptopManagementBLL.Instance.GetLaptopsInfo();
  }

  // UserAccountVM.PropertyChanged event handler
  private void UpdateReceiverIdOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(UserAccountViewModel.SelectedUA), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
      ReceiverID = UserAccountVM.SelectedUA.EmpID;    
    }
  }

  private string receiverID;
  public string ReceiverID
  {
    get { return receiverID; }
    set
    {
      receiverID = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ReceiverID));
    }
  }
}
```

**UserAccountViewModel.cs**

```
public class UserAccountViewModel
{
  private UserAccountModel selectedUA;
  public UserAccountModel SelectedUA
  { 
    get => selectedUA;
    set
    {
      if(selectedUA!=value)
      {
        // Removed wrong creation of LaptopManagementViewModel instances
        selectedUA = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedUA));
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked fine. I have more knowledge about "private" and "protected" access modifiers. I also learnt a new method to transfer data between ViewModel. I searched on some solution and forum to find out the solution for my question. They used PRISM’s EventAggregator to transfer data from this ViewModel to another ViewModel but It's so complicated with me.